# increase the downloads form value

Tags: javascript

I have a download button on my site and I want to increase the value of a form by 1 every time the user clicks on the the download button. I am using javascript and I am a bit successful in increasing the value of the input field by 1 but every time the page loads the value set backs to "0".. i want to know how to keep the incremented value unchanged and increase from the new value  every time the page loads..

I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function increase(){
var dwn = document.getElementById(no.dwn);
var value = dwn.value;
value++;
dwn.value=value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe increment the value on the server-side before serving out the file?

Comment: i wanted to if i can do that only with javascript but no php or other server languages

Comment: This 'number of downloads' figure is something you need all your users to see. Correct? In that case, the only way is saving it on the server.

Comment: you want to use server side language like php and store it to database.

Comment: yes i want to show the no. of downloads but i have no idea about php so i have a single idea that whenever the user clicks on a download btn the no. of downloads increases by 1.. can this be done by changing the value of "value" attribute as the increamented value every time user clicks on it..?

Comment: See this article http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/download-counter-in-php-using-htaccess/ and http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/php-mysql-download-counter/

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless. Your form won't save unless you have some sort of persistent storage (like a database, or a text file) on the server, and some server-side logic to do the saving.

JavaScript alone can't do it, you can try using localStorage but that also will only count for users individually (And not globally for all users who ever pressed your button).